# DataGrid binding not working in GroupItem style declaration

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, groupstyle

I'm having some trouble getting a binding to work that is defined in the resouces section of my user control. The same binding seems to work later on in the xaml when I bind it to a column of the datagrid. It just won't display data when in the style declaration.

The error I get is

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'ReceivedDate' property not found on 'object'
>   ''CollectionViewGroupInternal' (HashCode=5477078)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ReceivedDate;
>   DataItem='CollectionViewGroupInternal' (HashCode=5477078); target
>   element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type
>   'String')

The below binding ReceivedDate is not resolving at runtime.

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- Grouped Items Header: Show the messages in a group. ex: date received -->
    <Style x:Key="GroupedItemsHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True"
                              Background="LightGray"
                              Foreground="Black">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ReceivedDate, Converter={StaticResource DateToSortGroupConverter}}" Foreground="Black"/>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

In the code-behind for this UserControl I'm setting the itemsList as follows.

```
    void MailController_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentMailBoxContent")
        {
            var currentMailBox = ((App) Application.Current).MailController.CurrentMailBoxContent;
            var collection = new ListCollectionView(currentMailBox);

            collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ReceivedDate"));
            ContentDataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
        }
    }
```

CurrentMailBoxContent is an

```
ObservableCollection<MailMessage>;
```

and ReceivedDate is a property in the MailMessage class.

```
public class MailMessage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DateTime _receivedDate;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public MailMessage(){}

    #endregion

    #region Properties


    public DateTime ReceivedDate
    {
        get { return _receivedDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_receivedDate == value) return;
            _receivedDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ReceivedDate");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region methods

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I've tried changing the path of the binding to /ReceivedDate.

The thing that confuses me is that the same binding works when declared elsewhere. Such as in the various column headers.

Comment: The `Expander.Header` does not get one of your view models. Instead the header gets its own object that has 2 properties named `Name` and `ItemCount`. That is in fact some sort of limitation of the cool grouping Feature.

Comment: Unbelievable. The example I followed used name and I didn't clue in because name was also the name of the property in that examples data model. Thank you gomi42. Please post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Expander.Header` does not get one of your view models. Instead the header gets an object that inherits from `CollectionViewGroup` that has two properties named `Name` and `ItemCount`.

Comment: I 'm using a CollectionViewSource for grouping in my datagrid. My Group header is a TextBox binded to that Name Property you mention. I'm getting an error cause i'm trying to edit this read-only property. Is there a way i can bind my textbox to the Name Property of my items in my ObservableCollection in my ViewModel instead of the CollectionViewSource ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand what you want to achieve. ObservableCollection has also the `Items` properties that contains all items of that group. `Items[0].Name` will work in case there is at least one item.

Comment: Thanks ! I used the `Items[0].Name` and it worked ;)

Comment: I would never use indexing in XAML, because in case of clearing the ItemSource, binding errors will occure.