WPF DataGrid - odd binding error when using grouping
I've created a CollectionViewSource in my XAML:
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SearchResultsCvs" Source="{Binding SearchResults}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

Which my DataGrid binds to:
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SearchResultsCvs}}"

And its GroupStyle is set as follows:
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderThickness="0">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SampleName}" />
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>

                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>

You can a TextBlock in the Expander's Header which is bound to a property on my row item model called 'SampleName'. When run, I see the expected number of groups in the grid, with their child rows correctly rendered, but the group headers are empty and I see the following binding error for each group:

BindingExpression path error: 'SampleName' property not found on 'object' ''CollectionViewGroupInternal' ...

Any thoughts? 'CollectionViewGroupInternal' seems to be an internal .Net class (not my row model!).

Never mind, just found this duplicate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407822/datagrid-binding-not-working-in-groupitem-style-declaration
